# iOS URLSessionDownloadTask while screen is locked

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

My application downloads many small (about 500kb) files using `URLSessionDownloadTask`s. When the application goes to the background, the download continues (we implement `application(_:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:)` as required).

However, when the device is locked, download seems to *sometimes* pause. When going back into the app, it resumes and after another lock, download *does* continue in the background.

Comment: Can you detail "sometimes"?

Comment: I personally think this is expected behaviour, since your iPhone tries to save it's battery. I think the only way to get around this behaviour is to implement `UIBackgroundMode` `audio` or `voip`, so your app is 'always on', just like phone calls.

Comment: That's the tricky part. *Sometimes* is, well, intermittently.

Comment: What kind of URLSession are you using, or rather what configuration?